# Origin of прятки (Russian word for "Hide and Seek" game)

Tags: этимология

Does **прятки**, the Russian word for the game **hide and seek**, come from *пяток* (five), *пятка* (heel), or something else?

My guess is пяток, because of counting from 1 to 5.

Comment: It's like assume that what "frivolous" is related to "five" - why on earth "r" would be gone ;)

Comment: I just noticed actually that прятки contains a 'р', whereas пяток and пятка don't. I think this confusion was caused as I was typing прятки into Wiktionary's search field. They don't have a page for прятки, so пятки shows up as the spelled out version. My eyes are apparently still getting used to parsing the Cyrillic alphabet, because I didn't notice the difference and clicked on пятки, leading me to пяток and пятка. :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Neither. This word derives from the verb "прятаться", which translates as "to hide (oneself)".

Comment: Vilmar is right. "pryatki" word is from "pryatat'sya".
and it has nothing to do with counting and heels))) you can count up to 100)))

Comment: So the next question is: where does салки come from? :)

Comment: @ghostarbeiter: from *салить* "to grease"